# Tensorflow C++ YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I train my NN-model in python and load it in VS2015 C++. The piece of code:

---

```
    // The session will initialize the outputs
    vector<Tensor> outputs;

    // Run the session, evaluating our "c" operation from the graph
    status = session->Run(inputs, { "y_pred" }, {}, &outputs);

    // Convert the node to a scalar representation.
    auto output_c = outputs[0].flat<float>();
```

---

The y_pred is a 2-element tensor, so I use flat to get it. However, I got an error, "YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE", from EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT.

Anyone has this issue before? How should I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: using `auto` with Eigen is not advisable. Eigen makes very heavy use of expression templates

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I think I don't use Eigen. I even do not include eigen.h. That's weird...

Comment: the reference to the [flat function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1a67ce62becce1e70454d9756d1d5ed996) says that it returns Eigen types. Anyhow, did you check the size of `outputs`? Maybe try `outputs.at(0)` to include range-checks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a post in stackoverflow but I cannot make sure who is the original author. Indeed we need flat function.

```
session->Run(inputs, { "pred" }, {}, &outputs);
TTypes<float>::Flat indices_flat = outputs[0].flat<float>();
float coutput[6];
for (int i = 0; i<dataSize; i++)    { 
    coutput[i] = indices_flat(i);
    cout << "outptut[i]: " << indices_flat(i) << endl; 
}
```